# How to make the excel sheet protected and unprotected by using Excel VBA macro?

Tags: excel

All
I wrote an excel VBA macro code, to do some math and presentation, but the macro does not work well, because the sheet is password protected, so I need a VBA code, to be included in my macro, to make the sheet unprotected, then do the math and presentation, then return the sheet protected again with the same password .
We can assume the password is “hello”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Sheet1.UnProtect Password:="YOUR_PASSWORD"
```

and

```
Sheet1.Protect Password:="YOUR_PASSWORD"
```